# Get data from XML - jscript - TESTCOMPLETE

Tags: javascript, testing, jscript, testcomplete

I have problem. I need change this **value="0,20"** to **value="1,20"** in

```
<configuration>
<deviceConfiguration>
<devices>

<add logicalName="MainScale" type="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, XXX.XXX.XXX">
    <parameters>
        <add key="CustomWeight" value="0,20"/>
    </parameters>
</add>

</devices>
</deviceConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

How can i get this value? Thank you so much for help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information on how to work with XML files in a TestComplete script in the [Working With XML Files From Scripts](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/advanced/working-with-external-data-sources/files/xml.html) help topic. Here is a specific sample code that should work for your case:

```
function test()
{
  var doc = getActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
  doc.async = false;
  doc.load("d:\\test.xml");

  var node = doc.selectSingleNode("//devices/add/parameters/add[@key='CustomWeight']");
  Log.Message("Old value: " + node.getAttribute("value"));
  node.setAttribute("value", "1,20");
  Log.Message("New value: " + node.getAttribute("value"));

  doc.save("d:\\test_updated.xml");
}
```